# Is there some possibility to listen MakerDAO's LogNote events?

Tags: events, logs, makerdao

I wonder is there some possibility to **listen MakerDAO's LogNote events**, like we able to do with standard events.

What I managed to research:

I saw that **LogNote was listed as an event** from contract details

```
let contractIntanse = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
console.log("contractIntanse.events: ", contractIntanse.events)

contractIntanse.events:  {
  Approval: [Function: bound ],
  '0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925': [Function: bound ],
  'Approval(address,address,uint256)': [Function: bound ],

  LogNote: [Function: bound ],
  '0xd3d8bec38a91a5f4411247483bc030a174e77cda9c0351924c759f41453aa5e8': [Function: bound ],
  'LogNote(bytes4,address,bytes32,bytes32,bytes)': [Function: bound ],

  Transfer: [Function: bound ],
  '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef': [Function: bound ],
  'Transfer(address,address,uint256)': [Function: bound ],

  allEvents: [Function: bound ]
}
```

However, I was not able to check this properly, e.g:

**1.** **event.watch** does not work for me because of web3 v1

**2.** I tried using **WebsocketProvider**

```
web3.eth.subscribe("logs", { address: "0x23..." },
    function(error, result) {
        console.log("subscribe result:",result);
        console.log("subscribe error:",error);
    })
    .on("connected", function(subscriptionId) {
        console.log("subscriptionId:" + subscriptionId);
    })
    .on("data", function(log) {
        console.log("data:" + log);
    })
    .on("changed", function(log) {
        console.log("changed:" + log);
    });
```

However, I was not able to see smth when I trigger event

```
await contractIntanse.methods.rely(address1);
```

Here is related issue I managed to find
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1752

**3.** I also tried to use **getPastEvents**, as latest `issues/1752` suggested

```
const eventOptions = { filter: {}, fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' };
const events = await contractIntanse.getPastEvents('LogNote', eventOptions);
```

It works ok for standartd event. However, for **LogNote** I get an **error**:

```
Error: overflow (operation="setValue", fault="overflow", details="Number can only safely store up to 53 bits")
```

Eventually, I'm very confused, do we able to listen MakerDAO's LogNote?
Appreciate any help, link to docs, discussions etc. Thanks!

**ADDITIONAL:**

I'm using DAI contract
https://etherscan.io/address/0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f#contracts

Here is a commit was used for deployments on mainnet. I used as a base.
https://github.com/makerdao/dss/blob/6fa55812a5fcfcfa325ad4d9a4d0ca4033c38cab/src/dai.sol

The LogNote takes from LibNote. It what I'm trying to listen.
https://github.com/makerdao/dss/blob/6fa55812a5fcfcfa325ad4d9a4d0ca4033c38cab/src/lib.sol

Comment: Do you refer to DAI (https://etherscan.io/address/0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f#code)?

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone yes exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `LogNote` is an anonymous event it is cheaper but on the other side you cannot filter it using a topic. See [this already answered question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73087/how-can-i-send-an-anonymous-event-in-abi-anonymous-true-in-solidity) for more details.

Anyway, you can listen to all contract events and then filter in Javascript. [DAI](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f#contracts) in fact has only 3 types of event: `Transfer` and `Approval` - with 3 parameters - and `LogNote` - with 4 parameters. `LogNote` is fired only by `rely` and `deny` functions, so you can use the code below to listen those events:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("ws://localhost:8546");

web3.eth.subscribe("logs", {
            address: "0x731830527c286469E89b5e43030C1fA3D9d78f03"
        },
        function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.error("subscribe error:", error);
                return;
            }
            if (result.topics.length == 4) {
                // This is a `rely` or `deny` event
                let signature = result.topics[0];
                let sender = result.topics[1];
                let arg1 = result.topics[2];
                let arg2 = result.topics[3]; //this is always 0x0
            }
        })
    .on("connected", function (subscriptionId) {
        console.log("subscriptionId:" + subscriptionId);
    });
```

Please note you cannot distinguish from `rely` or `deny` only looking at the log, but you must check the original transaction payload.

Comment: yes, it works! thanks here is gist https://gist.github.com/svetlanama/01e37938be6103f4c8b8acb8b20df31c